# compare all the words in string against words in a list

Tags: python

1.I have a list of keywords, I am keeping them in list named dict as below:

> dict ["r
>   enovation","homeloan","personalloan"]

2.I have a dataframe with 1000 records and has two variable, application number(integer) and comments(string).
create variables in this datframe which are nothing but the words of dict eg. renobation, homeloan, personalloan etc.

I want to read all the string variable(comments) for all the records and want to identify if any of the word in string matches to a word in dict.If it matches, increment the count of that variable in output from 0 to 1.

eg. comment variable contain the string such as "customer needed the loan for renovation of his home"
My objective is to read all the word in this string which is

> ["customer","needed","the","loan","for","renovation","of","his","home"]

and then compare each word with words in dict which is

> ["renovation","homeloan","personalloan"]

.

since renovation is matching keyword, so renovation variable shall get a count of 1 for this particular record and so on. If homeloan was also present in the comment then homeloan shall also have count of 1 as output.

Need help on how to code this using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. One of them is (python3):

```
list_a = ["renovation","homeloan","personalloan"]
list_b = ["customer","needed","the","loan","for","renovation","of","his","home"]
result = {}
for index in list_a:
    result[index] = list_b.count(index)

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

> {'homeloan': 0, 'personalloan': 0, 'renovation': 1}